# printf style formatting without outputting

Tags: c, string, printf

What I'm trying to do is make a new `char*` using a syntax similar to `printf`:

```
char* myNewString = XXXXprintf("My string says %s", myFirstString);
```

Is this doable without printing to an output stream?

Comment: What is `sprintf()`, Watson?

Comment: RE: snprintf(). It doesn't prevent failures, it just changes the type of failure. You get truncation instead of buffer overflow. I doubt one failure is any better than the other. Also, on error, snprintf() returns -1. My RX is to allocate the largest buffer NOT the result of string injection, use sizeof(really_big) for n, and test the return against it for size and -1. IFF the return is GT 0, and LT  sizeof(string_to_keep -1) did things go well. The -1 is for a nul-terminator. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the `sprintf` or `snprintf` function.

Note that `sprintf` doesn't return a pointer to a newly allocated string; you have to allocate the string yourself, and make sure it's big enough:

```
char target[100];
sprintf(target, "My string says %s", myFirstString);
```

Unless you can be *certain* that the target is big enough, you should use `snprintf`, which limits the number of bytes copied to the target string.

`snprintf` returns the number of characters that would have been written to the target string. You can call `snprintf` with a null target and zero size to find out how many big a buffer is needed, then allocate the buffer and call it again to write to the target (**NOTE**: My original code sample had an off-by-one error.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *myFirstString = "hello, world";
    char *target;
    size_t size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "My string says %s", myFirstString);
    target = malloc(size+1); /* +1 for terminating '\0' */
    if (target == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size = snprintf(target, size+1, "My string says %s", myFirstString);
    printf("target = \"%s\"\n", target);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `snprintf` was added to C by the 1999 ISO standard. Microsoft's compiler doesn't appear to support it; it does provide a function it calls `_snprintf` which *probably* does the same thing.

There's also a GNU extension called `asprintf` which does allocate the string for you:

```
char *target;
asprintf(&target, "My string says %s", myFirstString);
```

If you use this, you'll have to use `free()` later to deallocate the string.  And since this is a GNU extension, it will make your code less portable.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, this is what `sprintf` is for: `printf` style formatting into a provided `char*`.

[This documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) covers `sprintf` and related `printf` functions. Be sure to consider using `snprintf` instead: proper usage will make it a bit safer than `sprintf` by limiting the number of bytes actually copied to the supplied buffer.

The usage is a little different from your example: you supply a buffer which is modified by the `sprintf`. The function *doesn't* return the result, like other `printf` functions, return an `int`: the number of characters printed.

```
char myNewString[MAX_LEN];
snprintf(myNewString, MAX_LEN, "My string says %s", myFirstString);
```

Comment: agree here.. using snprintf instead of sprintf is highly recommended!.. sprintf can often lead to unforeseen overflows.

Comment: You could also put a hard limit on format specifiers: %20.20s

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `sprintf`.

http://www.manpages.info/linux/sprintf.3.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind GNUisms, `asprintf` may be the closest thing to what you're after: it automatically allocates a buffer for you (but you *do* have to remember to `free` it afterwards).

```
char *target;
int ret = asprintf(&target, "My string says %s", myFirstString);
// if ret < 0, the contents of target are undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `snprintf`, it is safer than `sprintf`.

Answer (score -1):

sprintf should do that for you.

The only difference from printf is that the first parameter is a char* in which to store the string, i.e.

```
sprintf(myNewString, "My string says %s", myFirstString);
```

Comment: Apologies for mentioning cplusplus.com.